# In C, iterative function is not giving the right output which is supposed to be a number not in sum(from data entered by user) or in data array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, math, iteration

I am working on an assignment. My assignment is to:
Write a program to find the smallest positive integer that does not appear
in the array and can not be formed by the sum of two numbers in the array.Use functions-
*int issumof2(int data[], int size, int number)

int inarray(int data[], int size, int number)*
(size is the number of elements in the array and data is taken from the user)
I am really stuck on how to fix this. I don't know how to use both functions together to find the number. At this p

```
#include <stdio.h>
//function declaration
int issumof2(int data[], int size, int number);
int inarray(int data[], int size, int number);
int i, data[7], size = 7, sum, n=0 number=0;

int main()
{
    printf("Enter 7 numbers ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &data[i]);
    //function call
    inarray(data, size, number);
    issumof2(data, size,number);
    printf("Number is %d\n", issumof2(data, size,number));//this is most likely wrong
    return 0;
}
int issumof2(int data[], int size, int number)//add all combinations of data
{
    inarray(data, size, number); //calling inarray to check that number isn't in data
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)//professor told me to use j<i but it doesn't work for some reason
        {
            sum = data[i] + data[j];//gets the sum
            if (number != sum && number != data[i])
            {
                number = data[i]+1+number; 
                number++;
                data[i]++;//moving on to the next data
            }

        }

    }

    return number;//this is also returning number??
}
int inarray(int data[], int size, int number)//check if number is in array
{
    if (n <=size)
    {
        if (number != data[i])
            number = data[i] + 1 + n;
            n++;
            data[i]++;//moving on to the next data
    }   
    return number;//this is returning number
}

expected output:
Enter 7 numbers
1 2 2 3 4 3 1
Smallest positive Integer = 9
```

Comment: `inarray(data, size, number)` is supposed to return true or false depending on whether `number` is in the array. You need to call it in a loop. And similarly for `issumof2()`.

Comment: Calling `inarray` is rather pointless if you do not care about return value.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your `main()` function should be like this:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Enter 7 numbers ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &data[i]);
    while (inarray(data, size, number) || issumof2(data, size, number)) {
        number++;
    }
    printf("Number is %d\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

You then need to write the `inarray()` and `issumof2()` functions so they return `true` if the the condition is satisfied for the given number, `false` otherwise.  They aren't supposed to search for a number by themselves. I'm leaving this as an exercise for you.